# index.php codeigniter file doesn't load from server /var/www/html on aws lite

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter

I have installed mariadb and php56 on my aws server and put the website codeigniter files in /var/www/html. The httpd.conf is pointed to load from the same. When I have  a sample index.html in this directory I am able to see the contents on the website.

However when I try to put my actual codeigniter based website which has the regular index.php, the website just displays the directory structure, which means it hasn't recognizes index.php to load.

What could be the problem? Really appreciate your replies!

Comment: Can you access the following page in your website `www.yourdomain.com/index.php`?

Comment: if you have uploaded code igniter folder inside project folde in var/www/html then you have to access yourdomain.com/projectname/index.php/controllername

Comment: @webCode - Yes I did try that. however it just shows the contents of index.php in the website page. Further also note that I am still using the IP address rather than a domain name to search the site on the web.

Answer (score 0):

> the website just displays the directory structure

Do you see index.php in that directory structure? If so, the web server is not running PHP. You might not actually have it installed, it might be installed but you need to restart the web server, or many other potential issues that you'll need to debug and provide more information.

If you do not see index.php in that directory structure, then you likely uploaded the project folder inside the `/var/www/html` folder. For instance, if the project folder is named `my_project`, and that folder contains the CodeIgniter index.php, then take the ***contents*** of that folder and place it inside `/var/www/html`

Comment: Thanks! Yes I can see the index.html file in this directory. Doesn't rhel(with Amazon AWS) come with php. However I checked php -version and it does show up  "PHP 5.6.36 (cli) (built: May 10 2018 17:37:08)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies" So I assume PHP is installed!

Comment: I said `index.php`, not `index.html`. Check if the CodeIgniter `index.php` file is inside of  `/var/www/html` and not a layer higher or lower. Also, just because your terminal user has access to PHP doesn't mean the web server does. PHP can be installed/working on one and not the other.

Comment: Thanks @Goose. Sorry i actually meant index.php is present in /var/www/html directory. Ok. So even if I see the PHP loaded I have to cross-check its linking with my web server! - Is there a command way to check if the PHP is linked to my website?

Comment: @AnirudhThandra Can you login in to terminal as the web server user? Which web server do you have? If it's apache, it should be www-data.

Comment: -I went ahead and installed cpanel trial and now able to get everything up and running! - I wanted the command line way just to do it raw, but I assume cpanel spoon feeds everything and was an easier option. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: @AnirudhThandra Glad to hear it! Please accept my answer if you found it helpful